# Odoo record.write() to One2Many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

Hope you are well today wherever you are :)

I have one function that makes it possible to retrieve a certain fields from other models, which is using `self.env[].search`. I also successfully rewriting the `list of result`, but I stumbled upon a confusion where i would like to `update` that record into other fields using `record.write()`.

```
    @api.multi
    def _my_button(self):
        for record in self.env['created.model'].search([]):
            record_a = record.mapped('certain_fields') # saving result from certain_fields inside record_a variable
            record_b = self.number # A number defined by user in current Odoo <form>
            my_new_list = [number * record_b for number in record_a] # rewriting record_a values
            record.write({'destination_field': my_new_list}) #trying to put my_new_list to other fields
```

It's practically working when i change `my_new_list` to integer for testing purpose, but i couldn't get it work because dictionary doesn't seems to accept `my_new_list`.

Is there any way or alternative to write `my_new_list` within `record.write()` ?

Comment: It depends upon the type of 'destination field'. You could share how the field is defined in your model.

Comment: Hi @Nirmalraj , destination_field is an integer field which is inside One2Many rows. There are several rows that later i want to write using a list data type provided by record_b. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible... ans by Kenly should work, writing to One2Many fields should be in format 
[(0, 0,  { values })]

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `destination_field` field should be a [list of triplet](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L3540)

For example:

> (0, 0, values)
> adds a new record created from the provided `value` dict.

Try the following:

```
my_new_list = [(0, 0, {'final_qty': number * record_b}) for number in record_a]
record.write({'product_lines': my_new_list})
```

`field_name` is the field inside the One2Many field used to store `number * record_b` value

Comment: Thank you for the answer Kenly, i tried to write back with record.write({'product_lines':[my_new_list]}) but nothing happens, also there are no error showing in the log. Did i missing something in record.write() ?

Comment: Please show an example of the write values?

Comment: In your example `my_new_list` should be the list of tuples, do not put it inside a list. Try like following: `record.write({'product_lines': my_new_list})`

Comment: `my_new_list = [(0, 0, {'field_name': number * record_b}) for number in record_a]`
`record.write({'product_lines':my_new_list})`

after i checked the warning in log says "odoo.models: created.model.write() with unknown fields: product_lines".

when i changed product_lines with field_name it show error :(

Comment: What is the name of the One2Many field and the integer field?

Comment: One2Many field name is `product_lines` and the integer field is `final_qty`

Comment: The error message says that there is no field named `product_lines` in record model

Comment: i still figuring out what’s wrong about the missing record model, i will post the update later here

Comment: hi @kenly , after struggling few days back i successfully found the solution using another approach. Instead using `self.write()` to update One2many lines through button, I put context inside that One2many fields from XML views. So when user inputting value to `record_b`, it will be carried through context. And then, when user inputting `record_a` inside the One2many lines, `destination_field` will be filled with result from `record_a` * `record_b` using @api.onchange.